# Problems with macports

Tags: macports, cairo

I was having some other problems with some ports building for the wrong CPU architecture, and I'm trying to rebuild everything as universal.

I've done: `sudo port upgrade outdated +universal`, which ran for a long time, and seemed to install a lot of stuff I didn't need. But it didn't fail.

Then I tried with one of the libraries I was previously having problems with:

```
$ sudo port install cairo  +universal
Password:
--->  Building libpixman
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Log for libpixman is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_libpixman/libpixman/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade libpixman failed
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

Log is here http://hpaste.org/56449
(OSX 10.6.8, Intel Core i5)

Comment: These comments re homebrew are really off topic - this is subjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you've specified `+universal`, so it's trying to build for both 32 and 64 bit architectures (x86_64 and i386)...

```
:info:build --->  Building libpixman for architecture x86_64

...and then later...

:info:build --->  Building libpixman for architecture i386
```

but failing in the 32 bit build

```
:info:build ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libpng14.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

It's failing in the 32 bit build because libpng is built for 64 bit and can't link with the 32 bit version.

If you don't need a universal build, remove the `+universal` and the problem should go away!

If you do need a universal build... well, macports should figure it out.  I believe the issue is that libpixman does not declare dependencies on anything (libpng appears to be an optional dep).  Macports can't know it has to build a 32 bit version of libpng.  That's my best guess anyway.

Here is [exactly your bug](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/32260).  Unfortunately the maintainer's conclusion was that you should manually force recompile libpng as 32 bit.  This is a crappy solution as it breaks automated universal builds up to gtk2 and beyond.  The real problem is the missing dependency and that Macports can't know to rebuild libpng without it.

Comment: Thanks! I forced it to install 32bit libpng and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo port upgrade outdated +universal` will only upgrade ports which have changed since you installed them so if a port has not changed it will not be installed/recompiled.

The first step is not strictly required but will remove some issues when you have multiple version of a particular port. This step is to remove all inactive ports `sudo port uninstall inactive`

To recompile all your ports use `sudo port upgrade --force installed +universal` the keyword installed will get all your ports and the -force will make sure all are rebuilt.

To make things easier in the future you should change the macports configuration to build universal without having to do that on the port command. You do this by adding +universal to /opt/local/etc/macports/variants.conf